# .Net Core (2.1) User Session Settings

Tags: c#, .net-core, session-state

I am new to .Net Core so please forgive the silly questions.
I am writing the back-end to a new application which encapsulates all business logic for the given application and will then be packaged within a NuGet package for consumption.

Once completed, there are several ways in which this package will be used (1) by a Winforms application and (2) via a web service.
I have various data related to the current user session which needs to be stored and used at various points - such as a Process Identifier.
I had intended to store this information as a static variable but this will only work for the winforms application. Storing this data as static in a web service will mean other user sessions/connections will use the same data when they should each have their own process identifiers. I then thought of using httpcontext session but obviously this is only available in a web environment which doesn't fit for winforms.

My questions is really - in the net core world, where would it be best to store variables such as this which will last for the current user session but then be trashed on exit/completion of the process?
I had though about storing this information against the thread (putting async to one side for the moment) but this feels wrong - just a feeling - no solid reasoning.
Any thoughts/ideas on this from anybody would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you want is interested process communication.

It has nothing to do with .net core or winforms.

Basically you can keep data anywhere which is outside the boundary of winforms or service or webapp.

If the data is temporarily needs to be stored , you can keep data in cache (e.g. redis cache).

You can also keep data in database if permenant storage is required.

Both web app and winform and service should have access to database.

There should be a component which is polling to tell winform app or service when data is updated by web app.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently looking into the caching route. I don't want to use a database as it adds time and unnecessary hops but a cache may work - although likely to be memory cache rather than redis due to technical limitations.